# how do I print the contents of a Gridview in WPF using Printdialog

Tags: wpf, gridview, printing, printdialog

I've got a gridview containing several lines (~20-30) and a few columns (4-5) and I want to print it's content. I've tried using the PrintDialog' PrintVisual method, something like:

```
    private void PrintBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{

PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)

{

printDialog.PrintVisual(grid, "My First Print Job");

}

}
```

Of course, it didn't work fully, as it prints only the visible rows in the screen. How can I print the full contents???

Answer (score 2):

Printing in WPF is not trivial. Far from it actually.

I recommand using [SUT.PrintEngine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238135/WPF-Print-Engine-Part-I) then you can do stuff like:

```
    public static void PrintElement(FrameworkElement _PrintMe)
    {
        var suPrintVm = PrintControlFactory.Create(_PrintMe);
        suPrintVm.ShowPrintPreview();
    }
```